# How to click a link in a frame with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer, frameset

I'm trying to click on an anchor link within a page that'll open a new tab to export a PDF, but this link lives within a frame inside a frameset like this:

[image: html content]

I tried this:

```js
//[login and navigating to the page]
//wait for schedule page
await page.waitForSelector(`frameset`);

//select content frame
const frame = (await page.$("frame[name='link']"));

/*clicking the button after looking for it allow the page to scroll until the button is in frame before clicking it*/
const pdfExport = await frame.$(`a[href='pdf.jsp?clearTree=false']`)
await pdfExport.evaluate(b => b.click()); //error here

await browser.close();
```

but I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'evaluate')
    at C:\Projects\scrapproject\Main.js:69:25
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

it seems that it cannot find my a link button but I cannot figure out how to click it. Can you help me please ?

Comment: Can you share the page? It's not finding the element (`page.$` returns null when it can't find it).

Comment: you need to login into the page in order to find it sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to initialize and click on element which is on the main page and not inside the frame.
Puppeteer / Playwright have another context for interacting with frames.

Both frameworks have similar context for working with frames.

You can read more about frames context:

Puppeteer: https://pub.dev/documentation/puppeteer/latest/puppeteer/Frame-class.html
Playwright: https://playwright.dev/docs/frames

Here is an example snippet of working with frames based on your case:

**Puppeteer:**

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('<the actual page>', {waituntil: "networkidle0"});

// Search for the frame with tag name - link
const frameObject = await page.frames.firstWhere((frame) => frame.name == 'link');
if (!frameObject) {
    throw Error('Could not find frame with name: link');
}

// now you can click on the element from the frame - using Frame Object
const downloadLinkElement = await frameObject.$("a[href='pdf.jsp?clearTree=false']"); // init element
// Note: you can add some wait or other condition checker
await downloadLinkElement.click(); // click on the element
```

**Playwright:**

```
test('example switch to frame and click', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto('<the actual page>');

    // switch to the frame with name tag - link
    const frameObject = page.frame({ name: 'link' });
    if (!frameObject) {
        throw Error('Could not find frame with name: link');
    }

    // now you can click on the element from the frame - using Frame Object
    const downloadLinkElement = frameObject.locator("a[href='pdf.jsp?clearTree=false']"); // init element
    // Note: you can add some wait or other condition checker
    await downloadLinkElement.click(); // click on the element
});
```

Comment: thank you making it so clear but the error persist even with your solution it seems that it finds the frame in both my and your solution but either way the a link cannot be found.

Comment: Hi Lolozen,
try to iterate over all <a> tags and print the href so we can be sure it is the proper one.
Something like:

    const allLinks = await frameObject.$$('a');
    for (const link of allLinks) {
        const href = await link.getAttribute('href');
        console.log(href);
    }

Or console log the HTML of frame.
await frameObject.content() // this is the frame content.